# How do I use manual T-SQL transactions in BIDS with IIS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, iis, bids

I'm as green as they come when using BIDS and SSIS, just started today. I wanted to create a table and import some data into from an Access data file. I got that to work but I had to keep deleting the partial results and I thought wrapping it all in a Transaction would be a good idea. I'm not running MSDTC so I thought I would just use a manual transaction. I tried adding  an Exectute T-SQL Task that contained BEGIN TRANS then I added two more one with COMMIT TRANS and one with ROLLBACK Trans. If the Data Flow Task failed it went to rollback otherwise it went to commit. When it got to the commit, it always said there was no begin transaction. The package looks like this. Is this supported and I'm just missing setting some magic property to make it work?

[image]

Comment: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1585/how-to-use-transactions-in-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/

Comment: Thanks for the link, always good to know where to find tips. Unfortunately this one is about using the built-in transaction support that requires MSDTC which as I mentioned in my question I'm not running. I'll still spend some more time reading this though just to see what else I can learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As each of these tasks are run independently, this is why your begin/rollback/commit will not work. If you just want to delete all the data in the table, run a TRUNCATE statement on the table when the data flow task fails.
When loading like this, I usually clear the table and populate it each time to test the data flow task.

Comment: See my response to HLGEM, I was hoping to avoid truncating the table and starting over. I think what I'll do is Detach and copy the data base after I finish with each source. That way if the 6th source screws things up I can start over from a more recent save point.

Comment: How about having your source data as input files and using a stored procedure to do bulk inserts? These can then be wrapped with transactions. Or you can load your different data sources into different staging tables if that is possible. That way you know which one has failed and can just reprocess that. Once all the loads have completed successfully, you can combine all the staging tables into a single data table.

Comment: Hi, Use the RetainSameConnection property of the OLE DB Connection Manager. I came across this article which answers your question: http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/08/20/SSIS-Nugget_3A00_-RetainSameConnection-property-of-the-OLE-DB-Connection-Manager.aspx

Comment: Ha! Thanks. Perfect. I'm going to edit your post to promote this comment as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is my advice on how to appraoch this. I usually transform teh data so that no rollback is ever needed before I do a data flow to load to prod. SO I load to a staging table and tehn either clean the data or delete bad records or check for teh existance of somethign that would cause a rollback before I ever consider putting something inot a produuction table. If you have showstoppers they should happen long before you get to production. If you simply want to find and deal with the mallformed records, teh staging table will allow you to do that, send the bad data to an exception table etc, all without disturbing prod. When you have the final data flow to prod, everyting is know to be good at that point. We do thousands of imports and never need to rollback at the prod level.

If you really, really want to rollback at the prod level, you can do the import in an execute SQl task, after using the dataflow to populate the staging table, that is a stored proce with an explicit transaction and a try catch block to rollback in case of error.

Comment: I am doing everything in a staging database and this is a simplified example of what I want to do. I am going to be running some SSIS tasks many times on multiple sources. It would be nice if after doing 5 sources and I find out the 6th one has problems, if I could avoid starting over but it looks like maybe I have to have MSDTC for this. Not sure I understand why I can't open a TRANS and then COMMIT or rollback many tasks later but it seems that's not how this tool was intended to be used.